# Jquery validationEngine onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have this jquery plugin Jquery ValidationEngine which is trigger by this:

```
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
            jQuery("#editar").validationEngine('attach');
        });
</script>
```

and it works fine, but on the submit button I have this:

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);"  id="BotaoEntrar"/></td>
```

That onclick sends the password through a javascript file (THIS):

```
    function formhash(form, password) {
   // Create a new element input, this will be out hashed password field.
   var p = document.getElementById("p");
   // Add the new element to our form.
   form.appendChild(p);
   p.name = "p";
   p.type = "hidden"
   p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
   // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent.
   password.value = "";
   // Finally submit the form.
   form.submit();
}
```

So this thing right here "cuts" the validation jquery (if I remove the onclick it works fine, but then the encrypted password doesn't work) but I want the two things working together..

Something like "if validation is correct -> formhash.... else echo"error validation" " but I don't know much about jquery and javascript.. It's possible to have the two things working together?

Here is the API for the jquery validation: http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Comment: What if you try return `true` or `false` in the formhash method according to the validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate your form with `jquery validation engine` with your custom validations

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 jQuery("#editar").validationEngine();
 });


function formhash(form, password) {

if(jQuery("#editar").validationEngine('validate')){
//    first validates with jquery  validationEngine if retuns true then your validation takes place
// Create a new element input, this will be out hashed password field.
var p = document.getElementById("p");
// Add the new element to our form.
form.appendChild(p);
p.name = "p";
p.type = "hidden"
p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
// Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent.
password.value = "";
// Finally submit the form.
 form.submit();


 }
}
```